# Magento 2.3 add shipping line to cart totals

Tags: magento2, cart, totals

We use a quite simple shipping cost line. When the total is below 29.95 it adds 5.95 for shipping. If the subtotal is above 29.95 it is free.

Now I want to extend the default totals column in the cart, that between the subtotal and VAT we can add a line that adds the shipping.

We want to easily check if the subtotal is below 29.95 and than show the price, else we want to show the line: Free.

How can we achieve this?

I already tried the following in, but that does not work. It seems that it can not check the subtotal in that file; `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html`

Code:

```
<!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount < 29.95 -->
    <span class="shipping-cost"><!-- ko i18n: '5,95' --><!-- /ko --></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount > 29.95 -->
    <span class="shipping-free"><!-- ko i18n: 'Free' --><!-- /ko --></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```